# differentiating results of sql right join

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a below SQL query

```
SELECT `User`.`username` , Permalink.perma_link_id, Permalink.locale, 
    Permalink.title, DATEDIFF( CURDATE( ) , Permalink.created ) AS dtdiff,
    `TargetSegment`.segment_text, TargetSegment.source_segment_id, 
    TargetSegment.perma_link_id ,TargetSegment.created ,
    TargetSegment.updated,  DATEDIFF( CURDATE( ) , 
    TargetSegment.updated ) AS datediff
FROM `users` AS `User` 
RIGHT JOIN perma_links AS `PermaLink` 
    ON ( `PermaLink`.`username` = `User`.`username` ) 
RIGHT JOIN target_segments AS `TargetSegment` 
    ON ( `TargetSegment`.`username` = `User`.`username` ) 
RIGHT JOIN source_segments AS `SourceSegment` 
    ON ( `SourceSegment`.`source_detail_id` = `PermaLink`.`source_detail_id` ) 
LEFT JOIN source_details AS `SourceDetail` 
    ON ( `SourceSegment`.`source_detail_id` = `SourceDetail`.`id` ) 
WHERE `TargetSegment`.`username` = "xxxx"
AND `TargetSegment`.`segment_text` <> ""
AND `Permalink`.`perma_link_id` = `TargetSegment`.`perma_link_id` 
AND `TargetSegment`.`source_segment_id` = `SourceSegment`.`id` 
AND `Permalink`.`source_detail_id` = `SourceDetail`.`id` 
ORDER BY `TargetSegment`.`updated` DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 10
```

This SQL is fetching correct results for me.I want to identify from which table each row if from , to be specific which result is due to PermaLink table and which is from TargetSegment table.

is this achievable ?

Comment: can I use union to get the same result with an identifier for different table rows ?

Answer (score 2):

The rows don't come from one table or the other. Each row comes from **all** tables in your query. Corresponding data from each table is joined together to form one long row.

```
User.username                                                -- from User table

Permalink.perma_link_id                                      -- from Permalink
Permalink.locale                                             -- from Permalink
Permalink.title                                              -- from Permalink
DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), Permalink.created) AS dtdiff             -- from Permalink

TargetSegment.segment_text                                   -- from TargetSegment
TargetSegment.source_segment_id                              -- from TargetSegment
TargetSegment.perma_link_id                                  -- from TargetSegment
TargetSegment.created                                        -- from TargetSegment
TargetSegment.updated                                        -- from TargetSegment
DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), TargetSegment.updated) AS datediff       -- from TargetSegment
```

If the join condition fails due to a missing key in one of the tables and that table is the right table in a LEFT join or the left table in a RIGHT JOIN then all values from that table will be NULL.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you want to use aliases, like this:

```
    SELECT `User`.`username` , Permalink.perma_link_id AS p_perma_link_id, Permalink.locale AS p_locale, 
    Permalink.title AS p_title, DATEDIFF( CURDATE( ) , Permalink.created ) AS dtdiff,
    `TargetSegment`.segment_text, TargetSegment.source_segment_id AS t_source_segment_id, 
    TargetSegment.perma_link_id AS t_perma_link ,TargetSegment.created AS t_created,
    TargetSegment.updated AS t_updated,  DATEDIFF( CURDATE( ) , 
    TargetSegment.updated ) AS datediff
FROM `users` AS `User` 
RIGHT JOIN perma_links AS `PermaLink` 
    ON ( `PermaLink`.`username` = `User`.`username` ) 
RIGHT JOIN target_segments AS `TargetSegment` 
    ON ( `TargetSegment`.`username` = `User`.`username` ) 
RIGHT JOIN source_segments AS `SourceSegment` 
    ON ( `SourceSegment`.`source_detail_id` = `PermaLink`.`source_detail_id` ) 
LEFT JOIN source_details AS `SourceDetail` 
    ON ( `SourceSegment`.`source_detail_id` = `SourceDetail`.`id` ) 
WHERE `TargetSegment`.`username` = "xxxx"
AND `TargetSegment`.`segment_text` <> ""
AND `Permalink`.`perma_link_id` = `TargetSegment`.`perma_link_id` 
AND `TargetSegment`.`source_segment_id` = `SourceSegment`.`id` 
AND `Permalink`.`source_detail_id` = `SourceDetail`.`id` 
ORDER BY `TargetSegment`.`updated` DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 10
```

Than you'll see the permalink-columns prefixed with p_ and the other ones with t_